# Problemas com rotas MVC ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

Tenho um problema com rotas no MVC.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Essa rota, pras minhas páginas, funciona (pois não quero que tenha um Index na URL). Porém, quando preciso chamar um método do backend, preciso passar a action.

Como eu posso criar as rotas pra funcionar da maneira que eu preciso? Pra chamadas de métodos backend, preciso passar a action e pra URL de página, omito a action. E, por default, a action chamada nas URLs de páginas é a Index.

Answer (score -1):

Eu resolvi com uma "gambiarra": inverti ID com Action na rota, ficando {controller}/{id}/{action}. Assim, quando vou fazer uma chamada no backend, passou sempre o ID do item (ou 0 quando não tenho).

Consegui resolver meu problema, mas não acredito que seja a maneira mais correta de fazer.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema recentemente, onde eu queria montar um Admin, e página principal de cada área, exibiria os registros daquela entidade.

Era assim:

```
/Admin/Contato/Listar/
/Admin/Postagens/Listar/
```

Eu queria que fosse assim:

```
/Admin/Contato/
/Admin/Postagens/
```

Pra isso eu criei mais uma rota, onde só passasse o Controller como você fez, e uma rota mais especifica onde eu definia as rotas com Actions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Listar",
    url: "Admin/{controller}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Listar"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Eu coloquei nessa ordem pra exemplificar, mas normalmente você tem que adicionar rotas mais especificas primeiro, e depois as menos especificas.